# JQuery Slideshow by fadein/fadeout css background-image url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a slideshow in JQuery. I have a div that has a `background-image:url()` as CSS. I'm now trying to rotate this background image by swapping it with others and make a slideshow out of it.

I tried something but it's not working for some reason and I'm not sure why.

I also tried CSS keyframes but they are not really perfect when the slideshow goes back to the beginning, so it's not an option for me to use that.

I have exactly 6 images.

Here's my code:

```
var image = $('#slide-1 .bcg'); //this is my div container with the background-color:image() in it's css
var images = ["{{ 'slide1.jpg' | asset_url }}","{{ 'slide2.jpg' | asset_url }}","{{ 'slide3.jpg' | asset_url }}","{{ 'slide4.jpg' | asset_url }}","{{ 'slide5.jpg' | asset_url }}","{{ 'slide6.jpg' | asset_url }}"];

image.fadeOut(1000, function () {
    image.css("background-image", "url("+images[0]+")");
    image.fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use one of the many free plugins you can find online?

Comment: Because, I've searched around a lot and none of what I have found use this technique. I couldn't figure it out so I instead went with the same technique of <img> most people use. I still hope someone comes up with a nifty solution for this one. :-)

Comment: OK, so two things:
1- Isn't [this](http://slippry.com/examples/out-of-the-box/) what you are trying to achieve?
2- can you please at least make a fiddle of your code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so we can work on that?

Answer (score 0):

**The values within your `images` array are incorrect.**

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) page on how to use the `url()` value of background images. A value such as `{{ 'slide1.jpg | asset_url }}` will not display an image. Maybe you want just `slide1.jpg` instead?

Also, make sure you have an equal sign when assigning variables. On your second line, it should be `var images = ...`.